# When receiving an answer to a question do you respond with thank you?

Tags: etiquette

When I don't understand something in a lecture or think I found a mistake I send professors emails, if it is not possible for me to ask the question after class. Do you send a thank you email after receiving the answer?

I don't know if this is relevant at all, but I study at a German university.

Comment: I apply the manners I was taught by my parents - so do many of my students, they send a short email saying thank you...

Comment: Honestly, I prefer _not_ to get such mails. And I seldom send them to people I know unless there is some other content also. If I'm helpful to someone I assume they are thankful. If it wasn't helpful, we continue the conversation.

Comment: I like the "thank you" as it confirms 1) they received it and (probably) read it, 2) they can add that it now works for them.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of etiquette, yes. A simple "Thank you sir/mam" helps acknowledge their response. The alternative is to say the thank you to them when you meet them the next day.

Reason: Unacknowledged conversations tend to leave a doubt in anybody's mind about whether the response was useful to the recipient or not. Certain people tend not to reply to an email if they were offended or if an email didn't help them. So in the same way we were taught it is good manners to say "thank you", it helps to do the same via an email.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought some email that contained no information would be seen as rude. Now I get it:)